# $.when not waiting for ajax return

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
$('#mySelect').change(function() {
  $.get(
    "test.php",
    function(data) { alert('test1'); }
  );
});
```

I need to fire the event change of #mySelect, and wait for the answer of the ajax to perform a other task. But when I try

```
$.when($('#mySelect').change()).done(function() { alert('test2'); });
```

It only wait for the change is finish, and the ajax sended, not received.
So I have the alert 'test2' before 'test1'
How can I make $.when wait for everything inside the even to be finish?

Comment: The AJAX happens asynchronously, so it isn't blocking (i.e. it won't slow down the browser).

Comment: Btw you have a syntax error (the comma at the end of line 4)

Comment: Sorry for the syntax error, I just rewrite it for the question, I'm not at work, and the file are there... but I know I won't be able to sleep if I don't find an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quite close, you just need to return the deferred object in the `change` event anonymous funciton:

```
$('#mySelect').change(function() { 
    return $.get( 
      "test.php", 
      function(data) { alert('test1'); }//I removed the trailing comma here, it will cause problems
    ); 
}); 
$.when($('#mySelect').change()).done(function() { alert('test2'); });
```

This will return the deferred object associated with the `$.get()` AJAX call. That way the `$.when()` will wait for the AJAX call to complete and then run the function in `.done()` (you can also use `.then()`).

Comment: Both answer are great, but I decided to accept your answer since I don't have the need for global variable
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You must first save the deferred object returned by `$.get()` and use it in `$.when`.

```
var getReq;

$('#mySelect').change(function() {
  getReq = $.get(
    "test.php",
    function(data) { alert('test1'); }
  );
});

$.when(getReq).done(function() { alert('test2'); });
```